# Android protocol handler not recognized by NFC

Tags: android, nfc

In my app, I have created a protocol handler for myapp://. This works perfectly. However, the NFC system does not seem to "recognize" it. When I create an NFC tag with the URI "myapp://test", instead of directly passing it to my app, the dialog "Choose an action" appears. I can then chose "New tag collected", select "myapp://test" and my application is started.

Is there anything I need to do additionally so that NFC directly opens my app?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to add the action "NDEF_DISCOVERED" to the intent filter in the Android manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this issue by adding an additional [AAR record](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) (special NDEF record = Android Application Record) to your tag. Subsequently, only your app is starting and nobody is asking anymore.
There are several apps available which create this [android-applicationrecord](/questions/tagged/android-applicationrecord) for you.